# How to get rid the gap before an image is loaded?

Tags: flutter

I have an app where I'm displaying an image in the sliverappbar. When the page is loaded for the first time, the image isn't present yet. It takes a while to load the image and in that time, I get to see the backgroundcolor of the sliverappbar.

I referred to this thread - [Flutter: Preload images on SliverAppbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58013811/flutter-preload-images-on-sliverappbar), and followed what this said. Yet, that delay in loading the image is still there. Is there a way where I can get rid of the delay?

```
class DescriptionPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DescriptionPageState createState() => _DescriptionPageState();
}

class _DescriptionPageState extends State<DescriptionPage> {
  Image img;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    img = Image.asset("Assets/Images/bnha.jpg");
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    precacheImage(img.image, context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            leading: GestureDetector(
              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            ),
            shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50.0),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(50.0))),
            elevation: 5,
            expandedHeight: 200,
            pinned: true,
            floating: true,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              /*centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(
            'Boku no Hero Academia',
          ),*/
              background: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15.0),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(15.0)),
                child: img,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]));
  }
}
```

Comment: How about this answer (and the comment right below it)? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51343954/12086560 Preloading and caching your image before navigating to the page may resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) to cache image, for the first-time and updated image, you can use the placeholder parameter to put whatever default image you like.

UPDATED:
using FadeInImage.assetNetwork() instead

Comment: I believe cached_network_image is for images from the web. My image is an asset.

Comment: my bad, what about using FadeInImage.assetNetwork() instead: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/fading-in-images